# extend 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there an easier method to extend a **2-Dimensional** Array than this?

**My method:** I just created a copy of the original Array with one element more and then assigned the original array to the copy. It works, but I was just wondering if there's a better option than mine

```js
var a = new Array(1);
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  a[i] = new Array(4);
}
var help = new Array(a.length+1);
for(var i = 0; i < help.length; i++){
  help[i] = new Array(a[i].length);
}
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
    help[i][j] = a[i][j];
  }
}
a = help;
```

Comment: Code doesn't appear to work. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: `help[i] = new Array(a[i].length);` is out of bounds since there is no array in a at the last value of i. Perhaps you want to look at concat or slice or both. You do need to explain us what you are trying  - I am sure that `a = help;` does not do what you think it does

Comment: To extend a, just do `a.push([])`